# Android 11 mount namespace

Tags: android, linux, namespaces, root

I'm trying to mount a microsd.  As I understand it, this should be done in the global namespace.  Root - magisk.

I tried like this:
`su --mm -c mount -t sdfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /storage/0123-4567`
And also like that:
`nsenter -t 1 -m mount -t sdfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /storage/0123-4567`
As a result, the root namespace is mounted, but nothing is mounted in other applications.  how to mount to all namespaces?